# Is it possible to transform a CCR to a CCD using XSLT in BizTalk?

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk, hl7, btahl7

I have an existing .NET application that generates an CCR message that validates to the CCR schema. 
Rather that create a new application to generate the CCD I would like to use XSLT to map from my CCR schema to my CCD schema.

I am using BizTalk 2010 to generate the CCR Message.

Has anyone had any experience and success creating the XSLT for the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they're both Xml standards, there's nothing really preventing you from generating the comparable CCD using a Map, Mapper or custom xslt.

No, I've never tried this and given they're from two different bodies, you may find some implementation details do not translate very well.